# pause(Duration duration) vs thread.sleep(2000)?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, action

What is **pause(Duration duration)** present under actions class in selenium webDriver ?

This link : [Selenium docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) Has not provided enough information about pause method.
By method name and argument type it's seems like it will take Duration Object and this is how I had initialize it :

```
new Duration(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) ;
```

Is this method deprecated? if not then can anybody please provide difference between **Thread.sleep(2000)** and **pause(Duration duration)** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pause() method allows you to have a sleep inside an `action` chain as it returns the `Actions` back. So if you need to put a sleep between two actions it is useful. Otherwise you will have to split the `actions` and have a `sleep()` in between the two,

There is another overloaded method of `pause()` which takes a long for milliseconds as parameter. Easier to use this one, but it is an individual preference.

Comment: So if I have multiple actions and want my script to pause for some amount of time in between those action, then I should use action.pause() ? that means internally it is calling thread.sleep() method ?

Comment: Internally it uses a PauseAction class which in its perform() method calls Thread.sleep()

Comment: Okay this PauseAction class is now Deprecated. Anyways Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You saw it right. *Selenium* supports two `pause()` methods.

[**pause()**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#pause-java.time.Duration-) is  from the [**Actions**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) Class and both the methods can be used between two actions while generating a *composite action* containing all actions.

The pause methods are as follows :

- public Actions pause(java.time.Duration duration)

  The [**Duration**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) Class i.e. **java.time.Duration** is in [**java.time**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package where **Duration** is defined as *a time-based amount of time, such as '34.5 seconds'* etc. The *Duration* class models a quantity or amount of time in terms of *seconds* and *nanoseconds*. It can be accessed using other duration-based units, such as *minutes* and *hours*.
- public Actions pause(long pause)

  This method simply performs a pause defined in milliseconds.

Comment: Okay ! I am using : Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  action.pause(new Duration(10, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)); but eclipse is showing the error : the method pause(long) in action class is not applicable for the arguments(Duration) . Any insights would be helpful !

Answer (score 1):

Correct way of using pause method is as below: 
1) Duration object should passed using one of the static (factory) methods of the Duration class 
2) perform method should be called after the call to the pause method

Actions action = new Actions(driver)
action.pause(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).perform();