# Selenium WebDriver: Actions.Pause() vs. Thread.Sleep()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

While not ideal, there are instances where a hard wait is the only thing that works. In my quest to avoid `Thread.Sleep()`, I found `Actions.Pause()` which appears to have the same effect. Apart from chaining it with other actions, is there any other technical difference (or advantage)?

**Thread.Sleep():**

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

**Actions.Pause():**

```
Actions.Pause(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Build().Perform();
```

**EDIT:**

Not looking into method chaining which the other thread does not answer. Interested on the actual difference of the 2 statements as is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pause(Duration duration) vs thread.sleep(2000)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49624630/pauseduration-duration-vs-thread-sleep2000)

Comment: @Prophet Hi, it does mention the chaining which I am aware of and definitely an advantage. Trying to look into if the `Actions.Pause()` method was just used on its own.

Comment: So, in addition to all aspects discussed in the link above, does my answer answers your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internal implementation of

```java
actions.pause()
```

is

```java
public Actions pause(long pause) {
    if (this.isBuildingActions()) {
        this.action.addAction(new PauseAction(pause));
    }

    return this.tick(new Pause(this.defaultMouse, Duration.ofMillis(pause)));
}
```

where the pause action is actually involved by `new PauseAction(pause)`
The internal implementation of it is refenced to:

```java
public class PauseAction implements Action, IsInteraction {
    private final long pause;

    public PauseAction(long pause) {
        this.pause = pause;
    }

    public void perform() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(this.pause);
        } catch (InterruptedException var2) {
        }

    }

    public List<Interaction> asInteractions(PointerInput mouse, KeyInput keyboard) {
        return Collections.singletonList(new Pause(keyboard, Duration.ofMillis(this.pause)));
    }
}
```

So, as you can see internally it utilizes...

```java
Thread.sleep(this.pause);
```

Comment: Upvoted and accepted as answer. Thanks for showing the actual implem.